# pac4j Bad User Info response allows user to login

Tags: openid-connect, pac4j

I am trying to use https://www.pac4j.org/docs/clients/openid-connect.html docs to integrate my application but if access token destroyed(session destroyed in case of keycloak) using header client like below:

```
HeaderClient client = new HeaderClient("Authorization", "Bearer ", oidcClient.getProfileCreator());
```

allows client to login. It just prints a debug log like:

```
ERROR o.p.o.p.creator.OidcProfileCreator -- Bad User Info response, error=invalid_token
```

Previously there was UserInfoOidcAuthenticator for header client but it was deprecated and removed in pac4j 6.x. So how should i configure headerclient to achieve same functionality when we were using UserInfoOidcAuthenticator? Or am i missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not missing anything:

```
new HeaderClient("Authorization", "Bearer ", new UserInfoOidcAuthenticator(oidcConfig));
```

should be replaced by:

```
new HeaderClient("Authorization", "Bearer ", oidcClient.getProfileCreator());
```

But there is a bug in the latest pac4j v6.0.0-RC6. I just committed a fix. Can you check again with the 6.0.0-RC7-SNAPSHOT (available in the Sonatype snapshots repo)? Thanks

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think same bug exists in 5.7.x series as well. It does not return Optional.empty in case of access token

Comment: Indeed, I just committed the same fix for v5.7.x stream: https://github.com/pac4j/pac4j/commit/f37c4ae905ac63f493b793e97923b1e9458d021e Can you test again with the version 5.7.2-SNAPSHOT? Thanks